# Linq - Get groups of elements from List between two elements of the same type

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have the following list of URLs:

```
Url 1:  https://www.example.com/dummy-path1?<query-params-here>
Url 2:  https://www.example.com/dummy-path2?<query-params-here>
Url 3:  https://www.example.com/specific-path?<query-params-here>
Url 4:  https://www.example.com/path1?<query-params-here>
Url 5:  https://www.example.com/path2?<query-params-here>
Url 6:  https://www.example.com/specific-path?<query-params-here>
Url 7:  https://www.example.com/path1?<query-params-here>
Url 8:  https://www.example.com/path2?<query-params-here>
...
```

I want to take groups of elements so that in the end I'll have:

```
Group1:
Url 3:  https://www.example.com/specific-path?<query-params-here>
Url 4:  https://www.example.com/path1?<query-params-here>
Url 5:  https://www.example.com/path2?<query-params-here>

Group2:
Url 6:  https://www.example.com/specific-path?<query-params-here>
Url 7:  https://www.example.com/path1?<query-params-here>
Url 8:  https://www.example.com/path2?<query-params-here>
```

Note: It's not necessary that two groups will have the same number of items.

I tried a couple of LINQ combination of `SkipWhile` and `TakeWhile`:

```
var a = lines.SkipWhile(s => !s.Contains("example.com/specific-path"));
```

but when I'll try to apply `TakeWhile(s => s.Contains("example.com/specific-path"))` it will already fail because the first element (after `SkipWhile`) already contains `specific-path`.

How can I achieve this using LINQ?

Comment: Does `dummy-path` occur only at the start of the list, or also later on?

Comment: And what should the resulting datatype be? `List<List<string>>` or something different?

Comment: List<string> mystring = new List<string>() {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"};
            List<List<string>> results = mystring.Select((x, i) => new { x = x, i = i/(mystring.Count /2) }).GroupBy(x => x.i).Select(x => x.Select(y => y.x).ToList()).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is can be done with [MoreLinq.Segment](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#segment):

```
navigated.Segment(x => x.StartsWith("https://www.example.com/specific-path"));
```

---

```
var source = @"Url 1:  https://www.example.com/dummy-path1?<query-params-here>
Url 2:  https://www.example.com/dummy-path2?<query-params-here>
Url 3:  https://www.example.com/specific-path?<query-params-here>
Url 4:  https://www.example.com/path1?<query-params-here>
Url 5:  https://www.example.com/path2?<query-params-here>
Url 6:  https://www.example.com/specific-path?<query-params-here>
Url 7:  https://www.example.com/path1?<query-params-here>
Url 8:  https://www.example.com/path2?<query-params-here>";

var navigated = Regex.Matches(source, "https.+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value);

navigated
    .Segment(x => x.StartsWith("https://www.example.com/specific-path"))
    .Where(x => x.First().StartsWith("https://www.example.com/specific-path")) // skip first group that contains dummy path
    .Dump();
```

Result:

[image]